# Joomla 3.1.4: how to insert tags programmatically?

Tags: php, joomla

In Joomla 3.1.1, here's the simplified code that I use to batch insert articles (and tags):

```
$table = JTable::getInstance('Content', 'JTable', array());
$data = array(
    'title' => $my_title,
    'introtext' => $my_introtext,
    ....
    'metadata' => array(
          ...,
         'tags' => $list_of_tag[id],
          ...,
       ),
  );
$table->bind($data);
$table->check();
$table->store();
```

The `$list_of_tag[ids]` then goes into #_content `metadata` field in the form `{"tags":[ids],"robots":"","author":"","rights":"","xreference":""}`. Joomla also would take care of other related tables such as `#_contentitem_tag_map`, etc.

This method does not work in Joomla 3.1.4, as the tag no longer goes into `metadata` field, the new format is `{"robots":"","author":"","rights":"","xreference":""}`, i.e., no more `tags` key.

Does anyone know how do I insert tags into Joomla programmatically in 3.1.4? Thanks,

**Update for full code:**

The full code that worked in 3.1.1, where $row['tags'] is an array of integers, corresponding to exising tag ids in #_tags, and all other fields in $row are well defined.

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php');
require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php');
require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'factory.php' );

define('JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR', JPATH_BASE . DS . 'administrator' . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_content');

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');

require_once (JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_content/models/article.php');

$string = file_get_contents("items.json");
$json_str = json_decode($string, true);
$title_default = 'No Title';
$i = 0;
foreach($json_str as $row){
    $table = JTable::getInstance('Content', 'JTable', array());
    $data = array(
        'title' => $row['title'][0],
        'alias' => $row['alias'][0],
        'introtext' => $row['content'],
        'state' => 1,
        'catid' => $row['catid'][0],
        'created' => $row['pdate'],
        'created_by' => 635,
        'created_by_alias' => $row['poster'][0],
        'publish_up' => $row['pdate'],
        'urls' => json_encode($row['urls']),
        'access' => 1,
        'metadata' => array(
            'tags' => $row['tags'],
            'robots' => "",
            'author' => implode(" ", $row['poster']),
            'rights' => "",
            'xreference' => "",
        ),
    );
    ++$i;
// Bind data
    if (!$table->bind($data))
        {
            $this->setError($table->getError());
            return false;
        }

// Check the data.
    if (!$table->check())
        {
            $this->setError($table->getError());
            return false;
        }

// Store the data.
    if (!$table->store())
        {
            var_dump($this);
            $this->setError($table->getError());
            return false;
        }
    echo 'Record ' . $i . ' for post ' . $data['alias'] . ' processed';
    echo "\r\n";
}
?>
```

Upon on reading the docs, I have tried different ways to re-write the code:

1. Move the line that says 'tags' => $row['tags'], under metadata to its parent array, that is:

   ```
       ...
       'access' => 1,
       'tags' => $row['tags'],
       'metadata' => array(
           'robots' => "",
           'author' => implode(" ", $row['poster']),
           'rights' => "",
           'xreference' => "",
       ),
       ...
   ```

So now we have $data['tags'] populated with an array of integers mapping existing tag ids, presumabaly ready for the JTable store() method;

1. In addition to method 1, jsonify $row['tags']. for this I've tried two method:

2.a)

```
...
$registry = new JRegistry();
$registry->loadArray($row['tags']);
$data['tags'] = (string) $registry;
...
```

2.b)

```
data['tags'] = json_encode(json_encode($row['tags']));
```

With these changes I still can't add tags for the inserted articles.

Elin: Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Do you mean to put them in an  item to display? The simplest thing is to embed the tags JLayout in your view layouts.

Tags never should go into your content table .. the data are only recorded in the content_itm_tags_mapping table.  tagItem() is the method to this from JHelperTags

Comment: tagItem() needs $ucmId passed, how do I return this variable in the code? thanks,

Comment: That happens when the api does the saving, that's why the preprocessing/postprocessing is done.

Comment: I used the same code in 3.1.1, and it takes care of ucm table, tag map, etc, it just stopped working that way.

Comment: Well the thing is the documents show you how to add tags but you are oding it in a non standard way.  The changes in 3.1.1  did not impact anyone following the documentation.  Overall you should be able to do things in a non standard way of course.  To get the ucmId you need to get the id for the row in the ucm_content table that corresponds to the data you are tagging. you can get this from ucm_content or urm_content base, but note at this post that value is only created using the postStoreProcessing which creates the ucm_content row.

Comment: forgive my ignorance, i tried really hard to make sense from the doc, but to no avail:) I use either jtable or ContentModelArticle instance to populate articles into Joomla, and those are all that I know of, were you suggesting that there should be a more standard way? can you give a simplified code? I rarely need submit articles from frontend or admin, as I have >70k articles to insert initially and I feed about hundred more  articles by day, so being able to insert articles programmatically is essential.

Comment: So inserting articles using JTable is fine and will work great though without seeing your code it's hard to know exactly if it is ideal.  Tagging is accomplished with the JTable store() automatically if you have the tags you want in the data array for the article, just as if they were coming in from an editor.  Assuming your tags already exist you need to get the data into the Contentitem_tag_map table and that is waht the store() method does for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that if you instantiate JTable, then the new com_tags won't take `$data['tags']`, instead, you need to bind your tags directly to `$table` as `table->newTags = $data['tags'];`, this way your newly inserted articles will be tagged properly given that you have populated your $data['tags'] with existing tag ids.

Comment: Also there are some issues in 3.1.5 related to CLIs and JTable,

Comment: How about adding new tags?

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.joomla.org/J3.1:Using_Tags_in_an_Extension  is the basic documentation for using tags in an extension.

ALthough there are changes in 3.1.4+ if you follow these instructions it will work.  3.1.4+ makes it somewhat easier because it handles tags via an observer pattern instead.  I'll try to get the docs updated but you can look in any core component and see that the code as been simplified and moved somewhat out of JTable.

Update:

I updated the documentation for 3.1.4 including how to modify your old code to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but hopefully will save the next OP from the frustration I had trying to find a way to call the Tag methods directly.

I wound up simply updating the article to be tagged with the content model:

```
$basePath = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_content';
require_once $basePath.'/models/article.php';
$articlemodel = new ContentModelArticle(array('table_path' => $basePath . '/tables'));

$params = array(
    'id' => 123,                // Article being tagged
    'tags' => array(7,8,9,14)   // Tag IDs from #__tags to tag article with
);
if($articlemodel->save($params)){
    echo 'Success!';
}
```

Worked like a charm! It seems that it could be easily adapted to any taggable items.  I think I had a similar situation as the original question, and actually used the above code with a SQL statement that compiled the correct Tag IDs for me.  It would be meaningless to the answer, but it saved me having to manually tag 1,900 articles from a selection of 200+ tags!!